# product search by Category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to do search where c_id 3 then i will get product2. Again If i search c_id 1 then i will get product1, product3

**Here is my table structure**

```
p_id    p_name     c_id
------------------------
      |          | 
1     | Product1 |   1
      |          |
2     | Product2 |   2,3,4
      |          |
2     | Product3 |   1,2
```

Comment: Fix your data model so you have a proper junction/association table.  Do not store numeric ids as strings.

Comment: so what can I do ? Have any suggestion.

Comment: Go read up on proper database _normalization_.

Comment: @A.Developer you should have a relational database, should make things better. You can have a table that links `p_id` with `c_id`. Also if this is your "product" category, I'm assuming, you should have a unique ID for each record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: Hell, I would like to say that it is the wrong way of storing data. you are not following normalization and you need to learn normalization rules. you may be able to solve the problem but in future when your project reaches at higher level you will face many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find_in_set()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php),

```
select * from products where find_in_set(1,c_id);
```

OR

```
select * from products where find_in_set(3,c_id);
```

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/FMEZ35908)**

Comment: lol few month ago, I solved similar question and it was marked as duplicate and said one of the moderator told me instead of giving fish to the OP teach him how to catch a fish... lol I raised a question on stack exchange and everyone said it was right ... and now I am looking for the similar catch and no issue no duplicate nothing...

Comment: Full of as such baffles aye! A fortunate question is sometimes :D. Go with the flow mate ;).

Comment: yes,  I raised an issue on meta exchange why it is marked as a duplicate of theory-based question normalization... even on meta I got negative votes :P. and both the meta question and the one on stackoverflow got deleted. I wished i took a screenshot then I able to show it to you :P... i know there is nothing wrong with this question and your answer but I want to blacklist those fools :D

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/LXBE19424)**

```
  SELECT *
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE CONCAT(',' , c_id, ',') like CONCAT('%,', @search_id, ',%')
```

Comment: But as Gordon said this can only work with one c_id. is better fix your model for the long run.

Comment: not working I got a message unknown column `,%` in where clause

Comment: Yes I update the answer. I use back ticks instead of single quotes for the second %

Answer (score 0):

Using `FIND_IN_SET` could be an option **in the meantime**.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('specific c_id you are searching for', c_id);
```